# How to detect keys

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

I want to create table in which I want to configure hot key shortcuts.

I have this simple table:

```
    public static final String Column1MapKey = "A";
    public static final String Column2MapKey = "B";

    private ObservableList<Map> generateDataInMap() {
        int max = 110;
        ObservableList<Map> allData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        for (int i = 1; i < max; i++) {
            Map<String, String> dataRow = new HashMap<>();

            String value1 = "A" + i;
            String value2 = "B" + i;

            dataRow.put(Column1MapKey, value1);
            dataRow.put(Column2MapKey, value2);

            allData.add(dataRow);
        }
        return allData;
    }

public TabPane hotKeysContent(){

        TableColumn<Map, String> firstDataColumn = new TableColumn<>("Actions");
        TableColumn<Map, String> secondDataColumn = new TableColumn<>("Shortcut");

        firstDataColumn.setCellValueFactory(new MapValueFactory(Column1MapKey));
        firstDataColumn.setMinWidth(230);
        secondDataColumn.setCellValueFactory(new MapValueFactory(Column2MapKey));
        secondDataColumn.setMinWidth(230);

        TableView table_view = new TableView<>(generateDataInMap());
        table_view.setPadding(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));

        table_view.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);  // Autoresize when window size is changed

        table_view.setEditable(true);
        table_view.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
        table_view.getColumns().setAll(firstDataColumn, secondDataColumn);
        Callback<TableColumn<Map, String>, TableCell<Map, String>>
            cellFactoryForMap = new Callback<TableColumn<Map, String>,
                TableCell<Map, String>>() {
                    @Override
                    public TableCell call(TableColumn p) {
                        return new TextFieldTableCell(new StringConverter() {
                            @Override
                            public String toString(Object t) {
                                return t.toString();
                            }
                            @Override
                            public Object fromString(String string) {
                                return string;
                            }                                    
                        });
                    }
        };
        firstDataColumn.setCellFactory(cellFactoryForMap);
        secondDataColumn.setCellFactory(cellFactoryForMap);

        return null;
    }
```

I want when I click on a row into the second column to get the combination of keys which I will press and later to use these keys to activate keyboard shortcuts. Any example will be helpful.

P.S Table with the commands:

```
public static final String Column1MapKey = "A";
    public static final String Column2MapKey = "B";

    private ObservableList<Map> generateDataInMap() {
        int max = 110;
        ObservableList<Map> allData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        for (int i = 1; i < max; i++) {
            Map<String, String> dataRow = new HashMap<>();

            String value1 = "A" + i;
            String value2 = "B" + i;

            dataRow.put(Column1MapKey, value1);
            dataRow.put(Column2MapKey, value2);

            allData.add(dataRow);
        }
        return allData;
    }

    public TabPane hotKeysContent(){

        TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
        //tabPane.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 13pt;"); // Set size of the tab name

        Tab tabA = new Tab();
        Label tabALabel = new Label("Shortcuts");
        //tabALabel.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 12pt;"); // Set size of the tab name
        tabA.setGraphic(tabALabel);
        tabA.setClosable(false); // da se mahne opciqta da se zatvarq tab


        TableColumn<Map, String> firstDataColumn = new TableColumn<>("Actions");
        TableColumn<Map, String> secondDataColumn = new TableColumn<>("Shortcut");

        firstDataColumn.setCellValueFactory(new MapValueFactory(Column1MapKey));
        firstDataColumn.setMinWidth(230);
        secondDataColumn.setCellValueFactory(new MapValueFactory(Column2MapKey));
        secondDataColumn.setMinWidth(230);

        TableView table_view = new TableView<>(generateDataInMap());
        table_view.setPadding(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));

        table_view.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);  // Autoresize when window size is changed

        table_view.setEditable(true);
        table_view.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
        table_view.getColumns().setAll(firstDataColumn, secondDataColumn);
        Callback<TableColumn<Map, String>, TableCell<Map, String>>
            cellFactoryForMap = new Callback<TableColumn<Map, String>,
                TableCell<Map, String>>() {
                    @Override
                    public TableCell call(TableColumn p) {
                        return new TextFieldTableCell(new StringConverter() {
                            @Override
                            public String toString(Object t) {
                                return t.toString();
                            }
                            @Override
                            public Object fromString(String string) {
                                return string;
                            }                                    
                        });
                    }
        };
        firstDataColumn.setCellFactory(cellFactoryForMap);
        secondDataColumn.setCellFactory(cellFactoryForMap);

        tabA.setContent(table_view);                
        tabPane.getTabs().add(tabA);       

        return tabPane;
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Below is a SSCCE, though there is no tableView no column or cell. However the logic is similar. Examine it for clues and write your own code according to your needs:

```
public class ShortCutDemo extends Application {

    private KeyEvent shortcutKeyEvent;
    private EventHandler selectedEventHandler;
    private List<EventHandler> eventHandlers;
    private HBox root;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        root = new HBox(10);
        root.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
                // Do not filter for TextFields
                if (event.getTarget() instanceof TextField) {
                    return;
                }
                if (isKeyEventsAreEqual(event, shortcutKeyEvent)) {
                    // then apply shortcut event
                    selectedEventHandler.handle(null);
                    event.consume();
                }
            }
        });

        eventHandlers = new ArrayList<EventHandler>();
        eventHandlers.add(new EventHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handle(Event event) {
                root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: lightgray");
            }
        });

        eventHandlers.add(new EventHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handle(Event event) {
                root.setSpacing(50);
            }
        });

        ChoiceBox cb = new ChoiceBox();
        cb.getItems().addAll("HBox background = gray", "HBox spacing = 50");
        cb.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
                selectedEventHandler = eventHandlers.get(newValue.intValue());
            }
        });
        cb.getSelectionModel().selectFirst(); // default value

        final TextField textField = new TextField();
        textField.setEditable(false);

        textField.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
                if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.TAB) {
//                    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
//                        @Override
//                        public void run() {
//                            root.requestFocus();
//                        }
//                    });
                } else {
                    // Clear the previous text
                    textField.setText("");
                    // Process only desired key types
                    if (event.getCode().isLetterKey()
                            || event.getCode().isDigitKey()
                            || event.getCode().isFunctionKey()) {
                        String shortcut = event.getCode().getName();
                        if (event.isAltDown()) {
                            shortcut = "Alt + " + shortcut;
                        }
                        if (event.isControlDown()) {
                            shortcut = "Ctrl + " + shortcut;
                        }
                        if (event.isShiftDown()) {
                            shortcut = "Shift + " + shortcut;
                        }
                        textField.setText(shortcut);
                        shortcutKeyEvent = event;
                    } else {
                        shortcutKeyEvent = null;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        Button button = new Button("Reset");
        button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                textField.setText("");
                root.setSpacing(10);
                root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: white");
                shortcutKeyEvent = null;
            }
        });

        root.getChildren().addAll(new Label("Define a shortcut for "), cb, textField, button);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 900, 150);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private boolean isKeyEventsAreEqual(KeyEvent event1, KeyEvent event2) {
        return event1 != null
                && event2 != null
                && event1.getCode() == event2.getCode()
                && event1.isAltDown() == event2.isAltDown()
                && event1.isControlDown() == event2.isControlDown()
                && event1.isShiftDown() == event2.isShiftDown();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**How it works?**
1) Select an action (event) type from choicebox.
2) Focus to Textfield and type the desired shortcut, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> for example.
3) Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to focus out from TextField.
4) Press the shortcut (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> in this case) again to see the event in action.
5) Press "Reset" button to reset the state surely.

The further improvement should be defining a model class, that have ShortCut key, booleans for Ctrl, Alt and Shift, eventhandler to process and appropriately overriden `equals(...)` method.

Comment: By the way as far as I can see there is no difference in this example between right Ctrl and left Ctrl? I there a way to detect which one is pressed?

Comment: @PeterPenzov, afaik no. You can file it as feature request.

Comment: I would like to ask one more thing. I want to use the code that you wrote as answer. I tested to implement your code into the table which I added above but without any success. It seems that the table needs to be redesigned in order to be used with your code. Could you please edit you code and add the event listener into the table. I want when I click on the second column to type the key combination.

Comment: @PeterPenzov, set the cellFactory of the column. In there you will be creating a new custom TableCell which has a TextField inside. Apply onKeyPressed eventhadler to this TextField. Hint: see oracle's tutorial for tableview, "Example 12-11 Alternative Solution Of Cell Editing".

Comment: Nice!! Thank you soo much Uluk. :)
The event.consume() was the feature I was looking for^^

Answer (score 1):

Here's something that should get you started.  For simplicity I only handled ctrl and alt meta keys and only one column, but it should be obvious how to continue.  My approach was to use a [TextFieldTableCell](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/TextFieldTableCell.html) with a custom onKeyPressed listener that listens for key shortcuts and translates them into [KeyCharacterCombination](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyCharacterCombination.html)s.

Note that this example is not very complete or robust.  For example, single characters are not handled properly.  Standard shortcuts (Ctrl-C, Ctrl-V, etc) are not overridden.  You will probably have to implement your own TableCell class so you can fully control what text is typed.

```
public class KeyCombinationTableExample extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(KeyCombinationTableExample.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        final ObservableList<KeyCharacterCombination> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < 110; i++) {
            items.add(null);
        }
        TableView<KeyCharacterCombination> table = new TableView<>(items);
        table.setEditable(true);
        final TableColumn<KeyCharacterCombination, KeyCharacterCombination> column = new TableColumn<>();
        column.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<KeyCharacterCombination, KeyCharacterCombination>, ObservableValue<KeyCharacterCombination>>() {
                                       @Override
                                       public ObservableValue<KeyCharacterCombination> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<KeyCharacterCombination, KeyCharacterCombination> cellDataFeatures) {
                return new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>(cellDataFeatures.getValue());
        }
        });
        column.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<KeyCharacterCombination, KeyCharacterCombination>, TableCell<KeyCharacterCombination, KeyCharacterCombination>>() {
                                  @Override
                                  public TableCell<KeyCharacterCombination, KeyCharacterCombination> call(TableColumn<KeyCharacterCombination, KeyCharacterCombination> tableColumn) {
                final TableCell<KeyCharacterCombination, KeyCharacterCombination> cell = new TextFieldTableCell<KeyCharacterCombination, KeyCharacterCombination>() {
                    @Override
                    public void updateItem(KeyCharacterCombination keyCharacterCombination, boolean b) {
                        super.updateItem(keyCharacterCombination, b);
                        if (this.getItem() == null || b) {
                            setText(null);
                        } else {
                            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                            if (keyCharacterCombination.getControl() == KeyCombination.ModifierValue.DOWN) {
                                sb.append("Ctrl + ");
                            }
                            if (keyCharacterCombination.getAlt() == KeyCombination.ModifierValue.DOWN) {
                                sb.append("Alt + ");
                            }
                            sb.append(keyCharacterCombination.getCharacter());
                            setText(sb.toString());
                        }
                    }
                };
                cell.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
                    Set<KeyCombination.Modifier> keys = new HashSet<>();

                    @Override
                    public void handle(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                        if (keyEvent.getCode() == KeyCode.CONTROL) {
                            keys.add(KeyCombination.CONTROL_DOWN);
                        } else if (keyEvent.getCode() == KeyCode.ALT) {
                            keys.add(KeyCombination.ALT_DOWN);
                        } else if (keyEvent.getCode().isLetterKey()) {
                            items.set(cell.getIndex(), new KeyCharacterCombination(keyEvent.getCode().getName(),
                                    keys.toArray(new KeyCombination.Modifier[keys.size()])));
                            keys.clear();
                        }
                    }
                });
                return cell;
        }
        });
        table.getColumns().add(column);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(table));
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I use Java 8. `SceneBuilder, TableColumnBuilder, TableViewBuilder, KeyCharacterCombinationBuilder` are deprecated and the example is not working. Could you edit your example for Java 8 please?

Comment: I don't have Java 8 installed, but I removed all the Builder code so hopefully it should be compatible.  It's a shame they removed the builders, they were a joy to work with.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class KeyboardExample extends Application{
 @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) {
        final Keyboard keyboard = new Keyboard(new Key(KeyCode.A),
                                               new Key(KeyCode.S),
                                               new Key(KeyCode.D),
                                               new Key(KeyCode.F));

        final Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(keyboard.createNode()));
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Keyboard Example");
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private static final class Key {
        private final KeyCode keyCode;
        private final BooleanProperty pressedProperty;

        public Key(final KeyCode keyCode) {
            this.keyCode = keyCode;
            this.pressedProperty = new SimpleBooleanProperty(this, "pressed");
        }

        public KeyCode getKeyCode() {
            return keyCode;
        }

        public boolean isPressed() {
            return pressedProperty.get();
        }

        public void setPressed(final boolean value) {
            pressedProperty.set(value);
        }

        public Node createNode() {
            final StackPane keyNode = new StackPane();
            keyNode.setFocusTraversable(true);
            installEventHandler(keyNode);

            final Rectangle keyBackground = new Rectangle(50, 50);
            keyBackground.fillProperty().bind(
                    Bindings.when(pressedProperty)
                            .then(Color.RED)
                            .otherwise(Bindings.when(keyNode.focusedProperty())
                                               .then(Color.WHITE)
                                               .otherwise(Color.WHITE)));
            keyBackground.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
            keyBackground.setStrokeWidth(2);
            keyBackground.setArcWidth(12);
            keyBackground.setArcHeight(12);

            final Text keyLabel = new Text(keyCode.getName());
            keyLabel.setFont(Font.font("Arial", FontWeight.BOLD, 20));

            keyNode.getChildren().addAll(keyBackground, keyLabel);

            return keyNode;
        }

        private void installEventHandler(final Node keyNode) {
            // handler for enter key press / release events, other keys are
            // handled by the parent (keyboard) node handler
            final EventHandler<KeyEvent> keyEventHandler =
                    new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
                        public void handle(final KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                            if (keyEvent.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                                setPressed(keyEvent.getEventType()
                                               == KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED);

                                keyEvent.consume();
                            }
                        }
                    };

            keyNode.setOnKeyPressed(keyEventHandler);
            keyNode.setOnKeyReleased(keyEventHandler);
        }
    }

    private static final class Keyboard {
        private final Key[] keys;

        public Keyboard(final Key... keys) {
            this.keys = keys.clone();
        }

        public Node createNode() {
            final HBox keyboardNode = new HBox(6);
            keyboardNode.setPadding(new Insets(6));

            final List<Node> keyboardNodeChildren = keyboardNode.getChildren();
            for (final Key key: keys) {
                keyboardNodeChildren.add(key.createNode());
            }

            installEventHandler(keyboardNode);
            return keyboardNode;
        }

        private void installEventHandler(final Parent keyboardNode) {
            // handler for key pressed / released events not handled by
            // key nodes
            final EventHandler<KeyEvent> keyEventHandler =
                    new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
                        public void handle(final KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                            final Key key = lookupKey(keyEvent.getCode());
                            if (key != null) {
                                key.setPressed(keyEvent.getEventType()
                                                   == KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED);

                                keyEvent.consume();
                            }
                        }
                    };

            keyboardNode.setOnKeyPressed(keyEventHandler);
            keyboardNode.setOnKeyReleased(keyEventHandler);

            keyboardNode.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED,
                                         new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
                                             public void handle(
                                                     final KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                                                 handleFocusTraversal(
                                                         keyboardNode,
                                                         keyEvent);
                                             }
                                         });
        }

        private Key lookupKey(final KeyCode keyCode) {
            for (final Key key: keys) {
                if (key.getKeyCode() == keyCode) {
                    return key;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        private static void handleFocusTraversal(final Parent traversalGroup,
                                                 final KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            final Node nextFocusedNode;
            switch (keyEvent.getCode()) {
                case LEFT:
                    nextFocusedNode =
                            getPreviousNode(traversalGroup,
                                            (Node) keyEvent.getTarget());
                    keyEvent.consume();
                    break;

                case RIGHT:
                    nextFocusedNode =
                            getNextNode(traversalGroup,
                                        (Node) keyEvent.getTarget());
                    keyEvent.consume();
                    break;

                default:
                    return;
            }

            if (nextFocusedNode != null) {
                nextFocusedNode.requestFocus();
            }
        }

        private static Node getNextNode(final Parent parent,
                                        final Node node) {
            final Iterator<Node> childIterator =
                    parent.getChildrenUnmodifiable().iterator();

            while (childIterator.hasNext()) {
                if (childIterator.next() == node) {
                    return childIterator.hasNext() ? childIterator.next()
                                                   : null;
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

        private static Node getPreviousNode(final Parent parent,
                                            final Node node) {
            final Iterator<Node> childIterator =
                    parent.getChildrenUnmodifiable().iterator();
            Node lastNode = null;

            while (childIterator.hasNext()) {
                final Node currentNode = childIterator.next();
                if (currentNode == node) {
                    return lastNode;
                }

                lastNode = currentNode;
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```

}