# JavaFX WebView's edit box accepts ENTER key event

Tags: java, webview, javafx

I was wondering, how possible I can make JavaFX `WebView` to accept ENTER key event?

[image]

Currently, after finishing input username & password, pressing ENTER does nothing. I'm not sure whether injecting JavaScript code a good choice, as we have no idea what the HTML content is. The HTML content is originated from Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/events/handlers.htm). That should help. If the documentation doesn't help, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18585186/how-to-detect-keys) for an example.

If you want more specific help, please post some sample code for how you're currently trying to solve the problem.

**Solution : [JavaFX HMTLEditor doesn't react on 'return' key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11269632/javafx-hmtleditor-doesnt-react-on-return-key)**

Comment: But the event binding in documentation only applicable to UI component from JavaFX. Not UI component rendered from HTML by WebView.

Comment: Could you post your JavaFX code so we know what you have so far? If I understand your question, this might help. It's a JavaFX html editor, but the same principle may apply to JavaFX WebView. Again, posting code would be helpful

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11269632/javafx-hmtleditor-doesnt-react-on-return-key